# If $p>1$, and $p\mid mn\Longrightarrow (p\mid m \vee p\mid n)$ then $p$ must be prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, induction

I am trying to prove If $p>1$, and $p\mid mn\Longrightarrow (p\mid m \vee p\mid n)$ $\forall m,n \in \Bbb N$ then $p$ must be prime. any help ?

Comment: There seems to be some confusion here - the condition in the title is the *definition* of "prime", so it doesn't make sense to try to show that it implies $ p $ is prime.

Comment: "Let m be prime and let n= 1b.  That's only a single example.  Need to show this true for all possible.

Comment: Can you assume the unique prime factorization theorem?  If so this is straightforward.  If not you must prove the theorem.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Contrapositive: if $p$ is not prime, you can find $m,n>1$  such that $p$ divides $mn$, but $p$ divides none.

Comment: There's a bit of sloppiness in the statement of the problem.  There should be a "for all" attached to the $m$ and $n$.  Otherwise, it's not clear that this solution is really the contrapositive.

Comment: The ‘for all’ is obviously implicit.

Comment: @B.Goddard thanks very much for correcting me, I was missing "for all" and that's way I was struggling with this very simple question.

Comment: @Bernard, I immediately solved the problem after your hint, after I realized that I missed the crucial "for all" quantifier. Thnaks very much

Comment: Huh?  If it's always true for composite.  That doesn't mean it's not true for primes?

Comment: @fleablood: Is this comment for me?

Comment: Or any one who can explain.  I don't see how this is a contraposotive.

Comment: I suppose you agree   the contrapositive of $P\implies Q$ is $\neg Q\implies \neg P$ Now $P$ has the form $A\implies B$, and the negation of an implication is a counter-example, i.e. $A\wedge \neg B$. Now $B is a disjunction so you apply De Morgan's law. Is that clear?

Comment: $4 \mid 12=6\times 2$